# pcap_dump() lower permission to user only

Tags: c++, linux, file-permissions, pcap, libpcap

i'm working on improve a given code (don't know who wrote that )

i'm  using `pcap_dump()`and `#include <pcap.h>` to capture and wri  files to disk. 
The file that was writing is with read permission also for group and other (-rw-r--r--)

Is there a way to change it to user read/write only (-rw-------)
or that i'll have to do a workaround.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

new files are created using permissions from the current umask. 
umask specifies which permissions are *not* allowed, e.g. 
umask 077 means no permissions are allowed for group/other, 022 (the default) means write permissions are not allowed for group/other

You can set it in the shell before running your program, i.e.

```
umask 077
./pcap_program
```

you can also set it inside the program like this:

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/stat.h>

 void foo() {
     umask(0077);  
 }
```

note: the 0 at the start is required to make the number an octal number.

These will both set new file's permissions to 600 (= 0666 & ~0077), or `-rw-------`